# jQuery dont see onclick event on link inside infowindow in google maps v3

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, onclick

i have such problem that jQuery onclick event dont see click on link inside google map in infowindow.

Thats how my infowindow link looks like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/#ui-accordion-accordion-header-7" class="pull-right move-to-acc" id="itemH">See Details</a>
```

Under map i have acordion list with detailed information about point so im trying to catch click on that link move to accordion and open it - this is code i use to catch click event in infowindow:

```
jQuery("#itemH").click(function(event){
    alert("qq");
    });
```

When i click on marker infowindow open and i click on link but alert dont show up - im just moved to div #ui-accordion-accordion-header-7
If i put link outside the map jQuery catch click on link and display alert

What im doing wrong ?

Thx for help

Comment: At what point is the click handler attached - before or after the infowindow is created?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may Use

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '#itemH', function(event){
    alert("qq");
});
```

instead of

```
jQuery("#itemH").click(function(event){
    alert("qq");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with

> $("itemH").live("click", function(){ alert("Goodbye!"); })

Any dom update will attache a event listener only when you have live function attached.Try this out

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: Welcome Charles, but as Sheikh mentioned use live,on,delegate depending upon the version of jQuery you are using although functionality wise they are same ,i have attached the supported functions against the their version in my answer itself